# Pixel to Mesh visualization

Tags: c++, opengl, computer-vision

I have point clouds that I need to visualize, currently I use Pixel based representation in OpenGL, but I get many holes, I want to know can I generate and save data that MeshLab can open, or there is some library that works with OpenGl that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) which is a great library dedicated for point cloud visualization and 
processing.

[Visualizing Point Clouds](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php#pcl-visualizer)
[Fast Tranigulation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php#greedy-triangulation)

Answer (score 1):

The process you are referring to is called surface regeneration and can a quite complex process. Although there is no builtin support for this in OpenGL, there are libraries for doing this, e.g. [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/Chapter_main.html).

I am not familiar with MeshLab, but it seems to support many file formats e.g. [PLY](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/) which should be fairly easy to output.

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex [SOMENUMBER]
property float x
property float y
property float z
end_header
X0 Y0 Z0
...
Xn Yn Zn
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, I found other resources that solve my problem, I posted them so anyone can make use of them